# problem with push changes to remote server

Tags: git

I have a problem with GIT repository.
On the remote machine:

```
git init test.git && cd test.git
git config core.bare false
git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
```

In *.git/hooks* I have push-update file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This hook does two things:
#
#  1. update the "info" files that allow the list of references to be
#     queries over dumb transports such as http
#
#  2. if this repository looks like it is a non-bare repository, and
#     the checked-out branch is pushed to, then update the working copy.
#     This makes "push" function somewhat similarly to darcs and bzr.
#
# To enable this hook, make this file executable by "chmod +x post-update".

#git update-server-info

is_bare=$(git config --get --bool core.bare)

if [ -z "$is_bare" ]
then
 # for compatibility's sake, guess
 git_dir_full=$(cd $GIT_DIR; pwd)
 case $git_dir_full in */.git) is_bare=false;; *) is_bare=true;; esac
fi

update_wc() {
 ref=$1
 echo "Push to checked out branch $ref" >&2
 if [ ! -f $GIT_DIR/logs/HEAD ]
 then
  echo "E:push to non-bare repository requires a HEAD reflog" >&2
  exit 1
 fi
 if (cd $GIT_WORK_TREE; git-diff-files -q --exit-code >/dev/null)
 then
  wc_dirty=0
 else
  echo "W:unstaged changes found in working copy" >&2
  wc_dirty=1
  desc="working copy"
 fi
 if git diff-index --cached HEAD@{1} >/dev/null
 then
  index_dirty=0
 else
  echo "W:uncommitted, staged changes found" >&2
  index_dirty=1
  if [ -n "$desc" ]
  then
   desc="$desc and index"
  else
   desc="index"
  fi
 fi
 if [ "$wc_dirty" -ne 0 -o "$index_dirty" -ne 0 ]
 then
  new=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
  echo "W:stashing dirty $desc - see git-stash(1)" >&2
  ( trap 'echo trapped $$; git symbolic-ref HEAD "'"$ref"'"' 2 3 13 15 ERR EXIT
  git-update-ref --no-deref HEAD HEAD@{1}
  cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
  git stash save "dirty $desc before update to $new";
  git-symbolic-ref HEAD "$ref"
  )
 fi

 # eye candy - show the WC updates :)
 echo "Updating working copy" >&2
 (cd $GIT_WORK_TREE
 git-diff-index -R --name-status HEAD >&2
 git-reset --hard HEAD)
}

if [ "$is_bare" = "false" ]
then
 active_branch=`git symbolic-ref HEAD`
 export GIT_DIR=$(cd $GIT_DIR; pwd)
 GIT_WORK_TREE=${GIT_WORK_TREE-..}
 for ref
 do
  if [ "$ref" = "$active_branch" ]
  then
   update_wc $ref
  fi
 done
fi
```

On local machine:

```
git init test.git
touch file1.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin ssh://<REMOTE_REPO_ADDRESS> 
git push origin master
```

After all this opertions I don't have any file on remote machine.
When I use:

```
git status
```

I have:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    file1.txt
#
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I add some teks to the file1.txt, commit changes second one and push it to remote machine then I see the file.

Answer (score 1):

The remote end does not automatically track the head of its current branch in its working directory. If you do a `git reset --hard` on the server, you should see the correct files.

The reason it looks like your test file was deleted is because the head points at the new commit that you pushed, but the changes were not actually made to the working directory; only to the history. So the differences between head and the current directory include a missing file. Thus, Git assumes it was deleted.

This is one reason why repositories on servers are bare. Nobody should be working in that repository on the server itself, so there is no reason for it to have a working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You say "In .git/hooks I have **push**-update file", but the file should be called **post**-update.